# Add scroll event listener triggers one time only when intersection observer detects true or false

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, parallax, intersection-observer

I've tried to make parallax effect using only JS and I succeeded in controlling one section. Now I'm trying to make it works on multiple section on a page and I couldn't understand why.

The problem is scroll event listener triggers only once, when intersection observer detects true or false. I guess using only `addEventListener()` could work, but I what to use less resource by using `IntersectionObserver()`.

Here's my code i'm working on.

```html
<style>
.placeholder {
  width:100%;
  height: 150vh;
  background: royalblue;

.divider {
  height: 70vh;
  background: rosybrown;

.para-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1280/720');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
</style>

<header class="placeholder">Header</header>

<section class="para-section">
  <div class="para-content">Parallax Moving</div>
</section>

<div class="divider">Divider</div>

<section class="para-section">
  <div class="para-content">Parallax Moving</div>
</section>

<footer class="placeholder">Footer</footer>
```

This JS code works with one element, but not with multi-elements.
(am I doing right with add, remove evert listener? also curious^^;)

```js
const paraSection = document.querySelectorAll(".para-section");

const options = { rootMargin: "-100px" };

const paraObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      window.addEventListener("scroll", parallaxScroll(entry.target));
      console.log("ON");
    } else {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", parallaxScroll(entry.target));
      console.log("OFF");
    }
  });
}, options);

paraSection.forEach((element) => {
  paraObserver.observe(element);
});

// transform controll
const increment = -0.5;

const parallaxScroll = (element) => {
  let centerOffest = window.scrollY - element.offsetTop;
  let yOffsetRatio = centerOffest / element.offsetHeight;

  console.log(yOffsetRatio);

  let yOffset = 50 + yOffsetRatio * 100 * increment;
  element.style.backgroundPositionY = `${yOffset}%`;
};
```

If you have some better approach, any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks